# Xamarin odata POST method hitting multiple times and is using old data

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, odata

I have a Xamarin project that uses odata to communicate with a web api project.

When creating a new item in the database, on the first time everything works as expected and the odata POST method is only hit one time when hitting the line below in the Xamarin view model.

```
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The next time I try and save a new item the POST method is hit twice. The first time the data in the "challenge" object below, is the new data. Then somehow the POST method breakpoint gets hit again, and it has the previous items data. But, the xamarin view model SaveChangesAsync is only hit once.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Challenge challenge)
```

At the end of this operation, EF saves the object successfully. But, odata throws and error: "The context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri."

I really have no idea what is happening. I'm relatively new to Xamarin, and very new to odata. Is odata somehow caching previous POST data? I'm really lost and don't know how else I can try and debug this.

I've spent the last day and a half trying to google solutions, but I don't even know what to search at this point.

Info:
The web project uses MVC 5 with EF
The xamarin project uses Xamarin forms 5.0.0.2291
odata 7.9.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show a lot more code. Somehow the DB doesn’t know you already posted Create for the first item. Impossible to know why, without seeing all the steps. Everything involved in setting up the web communication and db. Maybe you’ve followed some tutorial, that didn’t clarify what should be done exactly once, the first time, vs what is done on each post. OR Maybe the response from first Post isn’t handled correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was initiating a new object in both the oData controller and in a web utility

```
var bar = new Foo();
```

and

```
var bar2 = new Foo();
```

So I assume oData was tracking a context of `bar` and EF was tracking a context of `bar2`

Once I changed that, it seems to be working as expected